# Linear Search Proof of Correctness (trouble with case where $ A[j] = v $ )

Tags: correctness-proof

There's lots of answers on the proof but I didn't find anything that regarded my difficulty directly.

**Question ( From " Introduction to Algorithms ( Cormen ) " ):**

[image]

**Answer ( Found on the net ):**

[image]

[image]

I don't understand the case where $ A[j] = v $ when we prove the maintenance step for before the *j+1*-th iteration ( after assuming $ A[j] \neq v $ for before *j*-th iteration ). why does the loop invariant hold in such case?

I don't exactly see how it makes sense since the program terminates in such case and so we're left out without having proved that $ A[j] \neq v $ for before the *j+1*-th iteration, but on the contrary we've shown that $ A[j] = v $ for before the *j+1*-th iteration, hence contradicting the assumption that $ A[j] \neq v $ for before *j*-th iteration.

Comment: When `A[j]=v` you don't proceed to the next iteration. In that case the program returns `i`, which is equal to `j`. When the program exists through line 5 there is nothing to prove. Line 5 is inside the IF and therefore, the condition in it must be satisfied.

Comment: What the paragraph is trying to prove is the assertion that when the program exits through line  8 then we know that `A[k]!=v` for all `k<A.length`. For this you need to assume that always the condition `A[j]=v` will not be satisfied.